# How to repeate normal column into multiple pages if that column is not column header in matrix ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2014

I am building a matrix based ssrs report and I want to repeat 2 column on multiple page( if extra pages is needed )and that column is not column header. it is static column. Please help me how its is possible

Comment: What the extra 2 columns mean in your scenario ? under the column group or out of the column group? If you mean the extra 2 columns are out of the column group . you could add the extra columns like [this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgTDB5EFt9TPgQIA0ZWHBvLndPDJ). If you want the columns are under the column group (seems it was not static),you need to add the null record in your dataset query.